# DataGridView : How to can I do multiline data entry in a usable way?

Tags: winforms, datagridview

With the DataGridView it is possible to display cells containing some long text. The grid just increases the row height to display all the text, taking care of word wrap and linefeeds.
Data entry is possible as well. <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Return</kbd> inserts a line feed.

But: if the cell only has one line of text initially, the row height is just the height of one line. When I enter text, I always see only one line. Ctrl+Return scrolls the text up, and I can enter a new line. But the last line is not visible any more, only the line I just enter.

How can I tell the DataGridView to increase the line heigth automatically while I enter text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an entry here from a DataGridView Program Manager [here](http://forums.microsoft.com/MSDN/ShowPost.aspx?PostID=60290&SiteID=1) that should be a good place to start.